# pandas row wise comparison and apply condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, row

This is my dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "name": ["bob_x", "mad", "jay_x", "bob_y", "jay_y", "joe"],
        "score": [3, 5, 6, 2, 4, 1],
    }
)
```

I want to compare the score of `bob_x` with 'bob_y`, and retain the row with the lowest, and do the same for` jay_x`and`jay_y`. No change is required for` mad`and`joe`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can first split the names by `_` and keep the first part, then groupby and keep the lowest value:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["bob_x", "mad", "jay_x", "bob_y", "jay_y", "joe"],"score": [3, 5, 6, 2, 4, 1]})
df['name'] = df['name'].str.split('_').str[0]
df.groupby('name')['score'].min().reset_index()
```

Result:

|  | name | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | bob | 2 |
| 1 | jay | 4 |
| 2 | joe | 1 |
| 3 | mad | 5 |